# evanscli exit repeated fields [grpc]

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

Hi guys i have issue exiting `repeated` field, i tried `ctrl-c` `ctrl-d` and i am still cannot exit this.

The structure is:

```
Events
 variant_set (field contain array of variant)
  variant (field contain array of value)
   value
```

in evans CLI this looks like this:

```
<repeated> event::variant_set::value (TYPE_STRING) => ctrl-c
<repeated> event::variant_set::value (TYPE_STRING) => ctrl-d
<repeated> event::variant_set::value (TYPE_STRING) =>
```

anyone knows how to exit this input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be avoided by specify `--dig-manually` option.

```
$ evans --proto api.proto repl
> call --dig-manually Unary
```

`https://github.com/ktr0731/evans/issues/574`